# Java program executes in eclipse but not in terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse with Eclipse Maven Plugin (m2e).

My java program compiles and run correctly from eclipse interface but I am unable to compile and run it from terminal.

My Eclipse Setting:

I am using two third party APIs, for which in eclipse build path I added

1. "/home/syed/workspace/FirstMaven/target/resources/fuse-jna-master/build/classes" **(as external class folder)**
2. "/home/syed/workspace/FirstMaven/target/resources/apache-jena-2.11.1/lib"  **(as external jars)**

Package:

```
package org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven;
```

My Project path:

```
syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven$
```

Source Code Directory Path:

```
syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/src/main/java/org/organization/upesh/FirstMaven$
```

Classes Directory:

```
syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/target/classes/org/organization/upesh/FirstMaven$
```

When I try to execute myProgram via below command

```
syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/target/classes$ java org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.myProgram
```

it gives me these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/fusejna/util/FuseFilesystemAdapterFull
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.fusejna.util.FuseFilesystemAdapterFull
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 13 more
```

But my test program that do not use the third party API runs correctly via:

```
syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/target/classes$ java org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.test
```

I think myProgram is not executing because of the two APIs (class folder and jar folder) that I am using.

I have added path of class and jar folders of the APIs to /etc/environment (given below) and rested my computer, but still the same error

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/syed/workspace/FirstMaven/target/resources/apache-jena-2.11.1/lib:/home/syed/workspace/FirstMaven/target/resources/fuse-jna-master/build/classes"
```

Please guide me how to run my program correctly

Answer (score 1):

JVM does not get libraries from `PATH`. It uses special environment variable `CLASSPATH` that can contain a list of directories or jar files separated by colon on Unix or semicolon on Windows.

So, just define `CLASSPATH` and put references to all your libraries there.

Aleternatively (and IMHO better) use command line switch `-classpath` (or its alias `-cp`) when running java:

```
java -cp mylib1.jar:mylib2.jar com.mycompany.Main
```

Comment: `syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/target/classes$ java org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360` gives the same error as mentioned in my question above and after including path as `syed@ubuntu:~/workspace/FirstMaven/target/classes$ java -cp /home/syed/workspace/FirstMaven/target/resources/fuse-jna-master/build/classes org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360` it then gives new error 
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360`

Comment: If your main class is in a jar, then the jar must be in the classpath.  If it is a class file without being in a jar, then it must be in the directory that corresponds to its package, and the root directory for that package must be on the classpath.